# best solution for java txt project

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Like topic says I'm looking for the best way to:

I got .txt file. In this file there are for example:

```
Matthew Sawicki 25\n
Wladimir Putingo 28\n
Barracko Obamaso 27
```

Whats the best way to write a program that opens this file, checks out the biggest number and then prints out that?

I was thinking about: open file -> check each line with hasNextLine method saving the biggest number (addin i for measuring the lines - 1, 2, 3) and then close file and open again and then somehow prints out that line

Ok there goes edit then.
By the way I have to write name of file in console to open it. And I have to use `Scanner`.
My code:

```
Scanner scanner= new Scanner (System.in);
File file = new File (scanner.nextLine);
scanner = new Scanner (file);
int temp=O;
int i=0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine) {
String word1=scanner.next;
String word2=scanner.next;
String word3=scanner.next;
If(word3>temp)
temp3=word;   
i++;  // now i get the i id of the line with the biggest number
```

And now I'm thinking bout reopen file and loop again to print out that line with the biggest number(By for instance `if(newWord3==temp))`
is it a good idea? And how to reopen the file? can anyone continue the code?

Comment: The best way is to continue to experiment with your code til you reach a solution. Don't give up yet as I'm sure that you can solve this! Consider reading each line and then splitting the line, getting the int and testing it all in your while loop.

Comment: Or, if every line has an identical format, reading two strings and an int on every pass of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this file will always be in the same format here's a snippet that does what you want with *no checking* to make sure that anything is in the wrong place/format.

```
    //Create a new scanner pointed at the file in question
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(new File ("C:\\Path\\To\\something.txt"));

    //Create a placeholder for the currently known biggest integer
    int biggest = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        //This line assumes that the third word separated by spaces is an 
        //    integer and copies it to the `cndt` variable
        int cndt = Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[2]);

        //If cndt is bigger than the biggest recorded integer so far then
        //    copy that as the new biggest integer
        biggest = cndt > biggest ? cndt : biggest;
    }

    //Voila
    System.out.println("Biggest: " + biggest);
```

You'll want to verify that the number in question is there, and that you can handle the case that a line in your text file is malformed

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. The way you described can work, but as you noted it requires to scan the file twice (in the worst case, which is when the row you have to print is the last one).

A better way which avoid to reopen the file again is to modify your algorithm to save not only the biggest number and the corresponding row number, but saving the whole line if the number is bigger than the one previously saved. Then, when you're done scanning the file you can just print the string you saved, which is the one containing the biggest number.

Note that your code will not work: the if is comparing a `String` with an `int`, and also there's no `temp3` variable (that's probably just a typo).

To follow my suggestion you should have something like this:

```
int rowNumber = Integer.parseInt(word3);
if(rowNumber > temp) {
    temp = rowNumber;
    tempRow = word1 + " " + word2 + " " + word3;
}
```

then you can just print out `tempRow` (which you should define outside the `while` loop).

Answer (score 0):

It's all fine now. I've made a simple mistake in my file (an empty enter at the end) so i coudnt figure out how to do it. 
Thanks for ur effort and gl!.